# Does the question "who are you taller than in your family" sound natural?

Tags: questions

Does the question *who are you taller than in your family* sound natural? For example:

> Your dad is the tallest in your family. Who are you taller than in your family?

What I am trying to ask who in your family is shorter than you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What I am trying to ask [is] 'who in your family is shorter than you?'*

That is exactly how most people would express it. *Who are you taller than?* is not idiomatic English, though it might be used by a child or in very informal speech.